# Consultar dados em PHP usando o método $.get json e listar dados em um html

Tags: php, mysql, json

Eu consigo fazer a inserção de dados mas não tenho ideia de como fazer a seleção de dados em um `HTML` usando `$.get` `JSON`.

*Codigo php*

```
public function Inserir($tabela,$sql){            
     ksort($sql);
     $Campos_nome=  implode('`, `', array_keys($sql));
     $Campos_valor= ':'. implode(', :', array_keys($sql));
     $novo=$this->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabela ( `$Campos_nome`) VALUES ( $Campos_valor)");
     foreach ($sql as $key => $valor) {
         $novo->bindValue(":$key", $valor);
     }         
     $novo->execute();            
     if($novo->rowCount()>0){
         $novo->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         $valor=$novo->fetchAll(); 
         print json_encode($valor,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
     }            
}//fim
```

Depois eu faço a serialização da minha `Form` envio os dados via POST para o meu arquivo `php`.
Aqui esta o código:

```
$("#novo").submit(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('action');  
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.post(url,data,function(data){
        $('#result').append('<div>'+o.nome+'</div>');
        console.log(o.nome);
    });

    return false;
});
```

Como faço para retornar os valores numa `tabela` ou `<li>` usando método `$.get`?

Obs: tentei fazer isso usando `append` mas não funciona corretamente:

```
function listar(){
  $.get(url,function(data){
     $('#div').append('<div>'+data.nome+'</div>');
     $('#div').append('<div>'+data.email+'</div>');
  )};
}
```

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta, como assim "seleção de dados em um html"? Ficou um tanto vago isso... No caso você quer filtrar as informações vindas no json?

Comment: Pode colocar o seu HTML para a pergunta ficar mais clara?

Comment: @Sergio ele precisa postar também o PHP, se não possuir um cabeçalho de retorno json, não vai resultar.

Comment: @Sam fiz um edição porque como agora eu sei que retornar um array então o código tem que ser aquele!!!

Answer (score 2):

No PHP nome do arquivo = json.php

```
<?php
 ...
 .../*consulta ao banco de dados*/
$rows=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
 $rows[]= $row;

}


header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($rows);


?>
```

No Javascript :

```
  $.getJSON( "json.php", function( json ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( json, function( key, val ) {
     items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });

  $( "<ul/>", {
   "class": "my-new-list",
    html: items.join( "" )
    }).appendTo( "body" );
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

No lugar do **o.nome**, coloque **data.nome**, porque, o seu paramento de retorno é o ***data***. Verifique se no retorno está vindo um json, com [json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) no seu [PHP](http://www.php.net) e acrescente no seu [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) na última configuração a palavra `'json'`.

```
$("#novo").submit(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('action');  
    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.post(url, data, function (data) {
      $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        $('#result').append('<div>' + value.nome + '</div>');
        $('#result').append('<div>' + value.email + '</div>');
     });
    }, 'json');

    return false;
});
```